# unexpected behaviour when extracting from lists with purrr::map

Tags: r, purrr

I'm having trouble understanding how purrr::map behaves, for instance, this works:

```
irisList <- list(iris, iris, iris)
carsList <- list(cars, cars, cars)
airqualityList <- list(airquality, airquality, airquality)

irisList %>% map("Species") %>% str(vec.len = 2)

> List of 3 : 
> $ : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 ...  
> $ : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 ...  
> $ : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 ...

carsList %>% map("speed") %>% str(vec.len = 2)

> List of 3
> $ : num [1:50] 4 4 7 7 8 ...
> $ : num [1:50] 4 4 7 7 8 ...
> $ : num [1:50] 4 4 7 7 8 ...

airqualityList %>% map("Ozone") %>% str(vec.len = 2)

> List of 3
> $ : int [1:153] 41 36 12 18 NA ...
> $ : int [1:153] 41 36 12 18 NA ...
> $ : int [1:153] 41 36 12 18 NA ...
```

and this also works:

```
mixedList <- list(iris, cars, airquality)

mixedList %>% map("Species") %>% str(vec.len = 2)
> List of 3
> $ : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 ...
> $ : NULL
> $ : NULL
```

Repeating but mapping for 'speed' or 'Ozone' gives the expected response. However,if I make it a bit more complicated things start to not return as I expected:

```
unNamedList <- list(list(iris, iris, iris),
                list(cars, cars, cars),
                list(airquality, airquality,airquality))
unNamedList %>%  map("Species")

> [[1]]
> NULL

> [[2]]
> NULL

> [[3]]
> NULL
```

According the the purrr user manual I should be able to do the following though if I have a named list:

```
namedIrisList <- list("iris1" = iris,
                      "iris2" = iris,
                      "iris3" = iris)

namedCarsList <- list("cars1" = cars,
                      "cars2" = cars,
                      "cars3" = cars)

namedAirqualityList <- list("aq1" = airquality,
                            "aq2" = airquality,
                            "aq3" = airquality) 

aNamedList <- list("flowers" = namedIrisList,
                   "autos" = namedCarsList,
                   "aq" = namedAirqualityList)

aNamedList %>% map("flowers","Species")

> $flowers
> NULL

> $autos
> NULL

> $aq
> NULL
```

So purrr::map 'knows' where 'Species' is, but doesn't return anything.

Since we know where 'Species' is located this should work

```
 aNamedList %>% map("flowers","iris1","Species")
```

But I get the same response.

```
> $flowers
> NULL

> $autos
> NULL

> $aq
> NULL
```

I think I'm not understanding how the extracting ability of map() is supposed to be used.

The context is that I'm dealing with a mixed list of bootstrapping results where the elements I want are in a large list of lists with different names and structures. I've been trying to access the 'list of list' components but it I keep getting 'Null' back from map().

Comment: I've used `modify_depth` (formerly `at_depth`) for lists of lists.

Comment: Also, `aNamedList %>% map("iris1", "Species")` works (not using the names of the top level lists because those are the lists that `map` is looping through).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `modify_depth` to pull out the desired vectors from a list of lists.  You indicate the `depth`, i.e., the level of list you want to work with.  In your example, you are working on the second level lists.

From the documentation:

> modify_depth(x, 0, fun) is equivalent to x[] <- fun(x)
>   modify_depth(x, 1, fun) is equivalent to x[] <- map(x, fun)
>   modify_depth(x, 2, fun) is equivalent to x[] <- map(x, ~ map(., fun))

So this code returns the either the `Species` column of `NULL` for every element of the nested lists:

```
aNamedList %>% modify_depth(2, "Species")
```

For a single element of a nested list (like `iris1`), you can use the names as you have been.  However, the top level list is what you are looping through and so you won't refer to those name. When you check, for example, `names(aNamedList[[1]])` returns `"iris1" "iris2" "iris3"` and not `"flowers"`.

You can use

`aNamedList %>% map("iris1", "Species")`

to get the `Species` column for any nested list named `iris1`.

Answer (score 1):

First get a hold of your data by viewing it. I use a combo of `listviewer` and and `str`.

```
listviewer::jsonedit(aNamedList) # interactive viewer
str(aNamedList, list.len = 10, max.level = 2) # play with list.len and max.level to adjust visible data
```

[image]

It's nice to look at just one chuck of data sometimes.

```
str(aNamedList[1]) # subset by 2 or 3 to get autos and aq
str(aNamedList['flowers']) # this also works with 'autos' and 'aq'
```

Use vectorized indexing to subset first for the 'flowers' list, then go to 'iris1', then 'species'. Like above, you can subset with int of chr strings

```
a <- map(aNamedList[1], c(1,5)) # all species from iris1
b <- map(aNamedList['flowers'], c('iris1', 'Species')) # identical to the line above
identical(a,b) # returns TRUE
```

---

What if we want all species in all lists under flowers (iris1, iris2, iris3 ...)

### 1. @aosmith's solution is excellent:

```
aNamedList %>% modify_depth(2, "Species")
```

### 2. Say you wanted only the flower information (not the null info from the other lists), you could first subset `aNamedList` to only include the flowers, then jump to level 2, and extract 'species'

```
aNamedList[1] %>% modify_depth(2, "Species")
```